# Manually typeset single and double quotations marks in dierect succession

Tags: symbols, typography, punctuation

Usually I use `\usepackage{dirtytalk}` to typeset quotation marks, however this usepackage does not seem to work within a `\textcite[Section: "This needs quotation 'marks'"]{source1}`  environment.

As indicated above, I need double quotation marks within the `textcite` option, where the last word in in single quotation marks.

Now, doulbe quotation marks can manually be achieved like ``` ``This'' ``` while single quotation marks can be type typeset like

```
 `this' .
```

**However** when typing the following

```
 Section: ``This needs quotation `marks'''
```

what is printed is **not** Section: "This needs quotation 'marks' " **but** Section: "This needs quotation 'marks" ' – i.e. the single and double quotation marks are in the wrong order.

How can I fix this?

MWE:

```
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@book{source1,
  author       = {Knuth, Donald E.},
  title        = {The {\TeX book}},
  date         = 1984,
  maintitle    = {Computers \& Typesetting},
  volume       = {A},
  publisher    = {Addison-Wesley},
  location     = {Reading, Mass.},
  options      = {skipbib}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}

 \textcite[Section: ``This needs quotation `marks''']{source1}

\end{document}
```

EDIT: Added MWE

Comment: I wouldn't use `dirtytalk` but rather `\usepackage[english=american]{csquotes}` and ` \textcite[Section: \enquote{This needs quotation \enquote{marks}}]{source1}`. I think `biblatex` often warns if `csquotes`  is not loaded.

Comment: Thank you @daleif! This works perfectly

Comment: I agree that `csquotes` is the way to go, but for a lazy solution, how about putting `{}` between `'` and `''`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution could be to use

```
 \usepackage[english=american]{csquotes}
```

(`biblatex` already recommends the use of `csquotes`) and then

```
\textcite[Section: \enquote{This needs quotation \enquote{marks}}]{source1}
```

Note how the `\enquote` macro can be nested.